# Controlling a File Upload Box with Python

Tags: python

I am wondering what modules or methods I should use to control a File Upload box from Python. I want Python to take control of this box when it pops up, and automatically navigate to a specific folder/file and select this file.

Comment: The box pops up from a WebKit browser instance, via the module Spynner. The OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the SendKeys module, which allows you to send keystrokes to Windows. Not perfect, but it works in the meantime.